# Using $variable in shortcode

Tags: shortcode

I will use an $variable who is outside the function.
In the shortcode function.

This is what i will do:

```
function shortcodevariable( $atts ){
    return 'echo $variable';
}
add_shortcode('variable', 'shortcodevariable');
```

I think we need an array but I dont now how, can somebody help?

Thank you very much.

Comment: from where come the data ? edit your questions to give more details.

Comment: The data variable is included in the page.php in Wordpress

Comment: It is for a wheather site, a Meteobridge uploads an php file with some $variable like: temperature, moisture, windspeed. This file with the $variable is included in page.php in Wordpress. Now I will shortcode the data in the wordpress pages.

Comment: It would probably be better to include that file directly inside the shortcode's callback function. Hard to say without an actual example of what's in that PHP file. It might provide global variables, functions or a class, that would all be used differently.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using PHP > 5.3, then you can use a closure on the `the_content` filter. This filter needs to be added after the `$variable` has been defined and before the `the_content` filter has fired.

```
add_filter( 'the_content', function( $content ) use ( $variable ) {
  return str_replace( '[variable][/variable]', $variable, $content );
} );
```

Shortcodes are process by core on `the_content` hook at a priority of 11. So any priority 10 or less will be run before that. If you want the callback to be run before `wpautop`, use a priority less than 10.

There's no reason to `add_shortcode()` because this code replaces the shortcode with the variable before `do_shortcode()` is run.

Filters should ideally be placed in the themes functions.php file, but if for some reason `$variable` isn't available to functions.php, then this little hack should work.

Answer (score 0):

I just discovered the solution to use external variables within shortcodes.

```
function show_shortcode_variable(){
    global $variable;
    return $variable;
}
add_shortcode('variable', 'show_shortcode_variable');
```

So if your `$variable = "foo";` and someone types this in Wordpress:

```
[variable]
```

... Then they'll see this output on their page or post:

```
foo
```

Your code is mostly okay, but you don't need the `echo` at the end, and you need to define the variable as `global` within the function.

Does that help?

Answer (score -2):

You have missing `shortcode_atts` and passing arguments in a shortcode. E.g

```
function shortcodevariable( $atts ){

   $data = shortcode_atts(              array(
                        'attribute-1' => '',
                        'attribute-2' => '',    
            ), $data            );

  return $data['attribute-1'];
}
add_shortcode('variable', 'shortcodevariable');
```

**Usage**

In a post, pages etc.

```
[variable attribute-1='okay']
```

In php file

```
echo do_shortcode ( "[variable attribute-1='<?Php echo $variable; ?>']" );
```

Recently I have created the post [Create a simple shortcode in WordPress](https://wp.me/p4Ams0-hC).

Comment: The answer of Nathan is right. But as a end user you couldn't use it in editor. If you use the shoertcode as a developer then the +1 for @Nathan answer.